# Students enrolled in 3 or more course

Tags: sql-server

I new here

I have 2 tables Subject and student 123 and I want to list the name(s) of subject and number of students taking it only if the subject has 3 or more students enrolled

```
SELECT

B.Subject_Name ,A.Student_Name ,A.Subjct_ID

FROM [dbo].[Student 123] AS A 
     LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Subject] AS B ON A.Subjct_ID = B.Subject_ID

GROUP BY A.Student_Name, B.Subject_Name, A.Subjct_ID
```

I'm stuck here, not quite sure how to get the list; any help will be appreciated

Comment: First step is to identify subjects that has 3 or more students enrolled. Hint : `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `COUNT`. Give it a try first

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have actully done thar but no result, though I know that "Math" has more then 3 students but i get no resut using this:                                            
SELECT 

A.Student_Name
,B.Subject_Name

FROM  [dbo].[Student 123] AS A
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Subject] AS B
ON A.Subjct_ID= B.Subject_ID

GROUP BY A.Student_Name, B.Subject_Name

HAVING COUNT (B.Subject_Name) >= 3

Comment: (1) remove `Student_Name` from `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` (2) change `Subject_Name` to `Subject_ID` in `SELECT` , `GROUP BY` , `HAVING`  . This will gives you a list of `SubJect_ID` with more than 3 students.

Comment: That works... Thank you so much, now I have the subjects with more than 3 student , ..... but I get blank when I add the student name........ Any more help please?

Comment: now you have a list of required `Subject_ID`. Next is to `JOIN` back to the `Student 123` to show the required information. You can use a `derived table` to do that. `SELECT * FROM ( <your last query> ) AS D INNER JOIN [Student 123] AS S ON S.SUBJECT_ID = D.SUBJECT_ID`

Comment: Wow, that works like  a treat, I'm most greateful... thank you so very much ......

Answer (score 1):

You want subject and number of students taking it. You can apply GROUP BY with HAVING clause.

```sql
SELECT B.Subjct_Name, COUNT(A.StudentName) as StudentCount
FROM [dbo].[Student 123] AS A 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Subject] AS B ON A.Subjct_ID = B.Subject_ID
GROUP BY B.Subjct_ID, B.Subjct_Name
HAVING COUNT(A.StudentName) > 3
```

I have provided sample below:

```sql
DECLARE @subject table(subjectid int, subjectname varchar(10))
declare @student table(studentid int, subjectid varchar(10))

insert into @subject 
values (1, 'maths'), (2, 'science')

insert into @student
values (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1);

SELECT sub.subjectname,count(*) as studentcount
FROM @student as stu
left join @subject as sub
on sub.subjectid = stu.subjectid
group by sub.subjectid, sub.subjectname
having count(*) > 3
```

| subjectname | studentcount |
| --- | --- |
| maths | 4 |

Answer (score 0):

First step is to identify the `Subject_ID` with 3 or more students. You use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to do this

```
SELECT A.Subject_ID
FROM   Subject as A
       INNER JOIN [Student 123] as B 
               ON A.Subject_ID = B.Subject_ID
GROUP BY A.Subject_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

Next, with the above result, you `JOIN` back to the `Student 123` to show the `Student` taking these `Subject_ID`